# WebFocus related query about date formats

Tags: date, webfocus

I am not sure this is the right place to ask about Webfocus reporting tool, but...

I want a date in WebFocus to display as `day-Month-year` (e.g.  4-Jun-2078).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'DMYY' as the format.

Answer (score 0):

WebFOCUS understands when you add the date in the below format:

```
&DMY  - ddmmyy 
&DMYY - ddmmyyyy 
&DATEDMYY - dd/mm/yyyy
```

You can also use:

```
D-M-Y  - dd-mm-yy
```